# openboot no signal at the end of boot

Tags: solaris

While performing an opensolaris 8 boot on sparc machine I can see all the messages from the kernel and the openboot, but once the boot is finished the monitor does not display the x login manager and a "no signal" message appears.
I suspect this is a problem with the x server configuration. How can I start it over with a default resolution or get the login manager prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean Solaris 8 (there was never an “OpenSolaris 8”), the `fbconfig` command can be used to adjust the resolution used by most SPARC frame buffers.   To run that, you may need to use `boot -s` to force going into single user mode to avoid starting the dtlogin manager that in turn starts up X.